# If timestamp includes certain time, then trigger an action

Tags: python-3.x, loops, date, datetime

I am trying to trigger an action, based on part of the timestamp.

Code (error is in line 3):

```
for ticker in tickers:    
   for i in range(1,len(ohlc_dict[ticker])):
      if ohlc_dict[ticker]['Date'][i] == "21:50:00":
```

ohlc_dict:

[image: Dataframe]

Now there are 2 issues with this:

1: It doesn't recognize 'Date' (KeyError: 'Date')

2: it should get triggered at this time on every single day (if timestamp includes "21:50:00" THAN ...)

Answer (score 0):

Just would like to answer an answer to my own question. I was over-complicating thing by wanting to do it all in that line. In stead, I went back to creating the dataframe and added this line:

```
ohlc_dict[ticker]['time'] = ohlc_dict[ticker].index.str[10:]
```

Causing 1 extra column in my DF with just the time, hence solving both issues.